# Laravel mix function inserts local paths on production server

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix

I have a Laravel application where I use the mix function in my blade templates to include my css and js files like this:

```
<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

This works locally but when I deploy the app to the production server, the mix function still inserts the local paths:

```
<script src="//localhost:8080/js/app.js"></script>
```

The APP_URL in the .env file is set and I've also cleared the Laravel caches.
Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: So this might happen if you're copying your files from your local to production and also include the "hot" files.

Comment: You are right, I deleted the hot file and it is working! Thank you so much!